# Validation with only one dataset

Tags: r, multiple-regression, cross-validation, multivariate-analysis, validation

I am performing multiple linear regression and multivariate analyses on a dataset (~600 samples). I would ideally use a second, independent dataset to validate my findings, but there is no suitable independent dataset available. How should I handle validation? Should I perform 5-fold cross validation on the one dataset that I have? Will that be sufficiently robust?

I am using R, in case anyone has suggestions for packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the small number of samples you have, you should definitely make use of cross-validation (5 fold should be fine). You should still have a holdout/test set to establish some form of generalization error.

All this said, without more data, you will most likely have to accept a simpler model (running a more complex model, e.g. one with higher number of variables risks serious overfitting) and consequently higher bias.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will do cross-validation  :)